# Getting background after removing foreground in OpenCV background subtraction

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, gaussian, background-subtraction, mog

I am using background subtraction, in particular MOG2 for video bgs with OpenCV.

I am currently getting the original frame and the foreground mask in two seperate opencv windows. I want to get a display of the background with the foreground removed. I am not able to find anywhere on how to do this. I can only find out how to extract the foreground from the background.

For example I have this as the original frame
[image]

This is my foreground mask
[image]

I want to attempt to display something like this:
[image]

Is this possible to do with just OpenCV?

Can I cut out the masks and then convert back to RGB? My end goal is to inpaint the white mask blobs.

Comment: Have you tried to invert the mask (swap ones and zeroes)? If your mask is np.uint8, you may do so by `mask = 255 - mask`

Comment: Since you already have the foreground mask, you can invert the image with `cv2.bitwise_not()` then bitwise-and with the original image